# Accessing 2d array with pointers in c++, how to assign address to pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am having a question in mind about c pointers to 2d array. We often write:

```
int (*p)[3]=a //here a is a 2d array
```

but writing as:

```
int (*p)[3]=a[0]
```

and

```
int (*p)[3]=&a[0]
```

produces the same result that is the base address of `a`. And if we `cout p`, it produces same result as `*p`.

Why this all is happening.

Comment: @Manu343726 the above *is* the declaration. `p` in `int (*p)[3]` is a *simple* pointer to an `int[3]` array while `p` in `int *p[3]` would be an array of 3 pointers, which would decay to `int **`

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
int (*p)[3]=a[0]
```

is invalid and the compiler shall issue an error. The right operand has type `int *` while the left operand has type `int (*p)[3]`

These statements

```
int (*p)[3]=a
int (*p)[3]=&a[0]
```

are equivalent because array a in the right side is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

As for statements

```
std::cout << p;
```

and

```
std::cout << *p;
```

then they produce the same result because they output the address of the memort where the array is allocated. *p is equivalent to a[0] and implicitly converted to pointer to its first element that is &a[0][0]. So in both cases it is in fact the address of a[0][0] because arrays are placed in memory by rows starting from the first row.

Comment: The first statement on the right hand side has type **int**

Comment: @David Kernin What statement are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read "2D array" and took a one-dimensional one

Comment: @user3287033 For example GCC issues the following error: prog.cpp:7:21: error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘int (*)[3]’ in initialization

Answer (score 0):

First: your code is invalid since there are no casts between incompatible types.

Array names used in expressions on the right-hand side are implicitly converted to pointers to the first element of the array. This is what's going on:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[][2] = { {0,0}, {1,1}, {2,2}};
    int (*p)[3]=(int(*)[3])a; // implicitly converted from array name to pointer to the first element (int(*)[2])
    int (*p2)[3]=(int(*)[3])a[0]; // a[3][2], access a[0], an array, implicitly converted to int*
    int (*p3)[3]=(int(*)[3])&a[0]; // Address of int[2] array, int(*)[2] type

    cout << p << endl;
    cout << p2 << endl;
    cout << p3 << endl;

    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/qG5riN

Answer (score 0):

this is because **array variables** are basically addresses.
so `a[0]` will point to the base address of the **First 1D array** because `a` itself is a **2D array**.